# Flickering IsGrounded function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

IsGrounded Function started flickering when I added OBJs to my project. It was working perfectly before I started working on it today it only started after I added some material and OBJS. I tried reverting to the state it was in before I added different elements but the problem still happened. It always occurs after about 30 seconds of running the game in the window. How can I fix this?

```
 \using System.Collections;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using UnityEngine;

  public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
 {

 //VARIABLES
[SerializeField] private float moveSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float walkSpeed;
[SerializeField] private float runSpeed;

public float _speed = 10;
public float _rotationSpeed = 180;


private Vector3 moveDirection;
private Vector3 Velocity;
private Vector3 rotation;

[SerializeField] private bool isGrounded;
[SerializeField] private float groundCheckDistance;
[SerializeField] private LayerMask groundMask;
[SerializeField] private float gravity;

[SerializeField] private float jumpHeight;

//REFERNCES
private CharacterController controller;

private void Start()
{
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();

}
private void Update()
{
    

    Move();

    this.rotation = new Vector3(0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * _rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

    Vector3 move = new Vector3(0, 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime);
    move = this.transform.TransformDirection(move);
    controller.Move(move * _speed);
    this.transform.Rotate(this.rotation);


}

private void Move()
{

    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(transform.position, groundCheckDistance, groundMask);

    if (isGrounded && Velocity.y < 0)
    {
        Velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float moveZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    moveDirection = new Vector3(0, 0, moveZ);

    if (isGrounded)
    {
        if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero && !Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
        {
            Walk();
        }

        else if (moveDirection != Vector3.zero && Input.GetButtonDown("Fire3"))
        {
            Run();
        }

        else if (moveDirection == Vector3.zero)
        {
            Idle();
        }

        moveDirection *= moveSpeed;

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            Jump();
        }

    }



    controller.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

    Velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(Velocity * Time.deltaTime);


}
private void Idle()
{

}
private void Walk()
{
    moveSpeed = walkSpeed;
}
private void Run()
{
    moveSpeed = runSpeed;
}
private void Jump()
{
    Velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2 * gravity);
}
```

}

Comment: @MickyD no, where? A velocity already is a frame-rate independent "vector per second" ;)

Comment: I'm a little bit confused how your movement in `Update` and in `Move` work together tbh

Comment: @derHugo ah of course.  I thought I saw a `+=` there...another other things.  _Another coffee for Micky_ ;)